# Website deep folder structure urls, but with all files kept at a shallow level folder

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directory

I'm developing a small web app that outputs details of properties (houses, hotels or whatever). The url to the app currently has ids for clients and properties in the querystring, then as a user browses the property a hash tag is modified to denote which part of the property is currently being viewed, so for example:

```
www.mydomain/myappfolder/?client=c0123&property=p001234#area=01
```

However, I don't want to use querystrings at all anymore and would like give out and use easy to read and more SEO friendly urls, so that they look like e.g.

```
www.mydomain/myappfolder/myclientsname/propertyname/#area=01
```

The app would then parse the url folder path instead of the querystring to output the correct content.

My concern is that when visiting a url formatted like this, the server wants to find a file at the end of the deep folder structure, and that adding files to all those deep folders will make it hard to keep the files maintained over time.

So my question is: does anyone know of a way that I can use deep folder structure urls like this, while still keeping all the app's files themselves at the shallower `myappfolder/` level?

I would like to keep the url showing as it is in the browser and in my web stats, so I'd like to avoid a page redirect if possible.

If this can't be done, can anyone propose the minimum I would need to put in a file at the end of the deep folder structure, so that it keeps the updating down to a minimum. I'm thinking this would need to be some kind of server side master page type system, and that this would need to point back to the path of where the app itself is located.

To add complexity, as some clients have their own sub clients, and some properties are sometimes categorised by location or by a project, different clients could need to have a different number of levels of subfolder, so we could also have e.g.

```
www.mydomain/myappfolder/myclientsname/theirclientsname/townname/propertyname/#area=01
```

Also, I'm trying to write the code so that it works in all situations, but the app can hosted by the clients themselves. This means they can put it where they want and move it around at some point in the future, so I can't know when writing the code where within their own website's folder structure the app will be placed.

These two details mean it is difficult for me to write code to live on a page in the deep folder, that refers back where the appfolder is located, as the page in the deep folder doesn't know how deep it is relative to the app, so it hard to use some kind of `../../` path. Also, it doesn't know where the appfolder is relative to the root of the website, because the client can put the appfolder wherever they want.

It could be done by getting the client to amend a config file that lives in the root of their site, but I'd rather avoid this as it would be too easy for something to go wrong with this in the future, and I'd rather avoid polluting the client's domain root.

Or I could write code that parses the url to try and read where the appfolder is by detecting the name of the app. However, we'd like the appfolder's name need to be plain English and a strong SEO keyword, so there is a small risk that the name could be duplicated in either a client's name or their project name, or the property's name or whatever. So I can't think of a way to be completely sure that the url parser has got hold of the correct folder.

Thanks very much for taking the time to read this far, even if you can't help.

UPDATE 1:

OK, so with all responses so far very helpfully suggesting using rewrite rules (which I have no experience of yet), I've read around and it seems like a good way forward, and I accept that I'm going to have to rewrite to a querystring. So...

```
www.mydomain/myappfolder/myclientsname/propertyname/
```

... would in my case be rewritten to ...

```
www.mydomain/myappfolder/?property=myclientsname/propertyname/
```

To avoid having to amend a domain root .htaccess file, I'd like to place it in the root of the myappfolder/.

However, as mentioned, I don't know where the myappfolder/ will be located, so I would need to create something that doesn't define the rewrite's target to a location statically relative to the root of the domain, as it could be in a subfolder or deeper. For example, is there someway to write it so that it is relative to where it finds the .htaccess file?

Also, as the myappfolder/ will contain physical subfolders for libs/ js/ etc., can anyone help indicate how I can avoid these being rewritten?

Comment: I think this is usually done using rewrite rules on the server.

Comment: You can use URL rewriting to map URLs (existing or otherwise) to physical files.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I'm understanding this correctly, you want to keep your URLs short, while keeping your files well organized. I would suggest a mod-rewrite and a database.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /myappfolder/?client=$1&subClient=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /myappfolder/?client=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

So that would take a URLs like this:

```
/appfolder/JaneDoe/p1234
/appfolder/JaneDoe/JimmyJones/p1234
```

And send it to

```
/myappfolder/?client=JaneDoe&id=p1234
/myappfolder/?client=JaneDoe&subClient=JimmyJones&id=p1234
```

I'm using different names to keep things short.

Then, I would assume you don't want long numbers at the end, so set up a database for each main client, and tables for them and their clients.

Simple query after that

**Update:**

```
SELECT * FROM 'JaneDoe'.'main' WHERE id='p1234'
SELECT * FROM 'JaneDoe'.'JimmyJones' WHERE id='p1234'
```

Then those results return anything you need, like a path to a deep level folder.

I would also suggest creating a simple CMS system to manage it, so you don't have to worry about typos between different areas or anything.

Hopefully that helps you get started.

BTW, I think my SQL syntax is off. Consider that pseudo code.

** Update: **

Here is an expansion on the Mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /myappfolder/?client=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Each `(.*) corresponds to a number, there are two, which is where`$1`and`$2` come from.

`^` means beginning
`$` means end
By placing these on the extremities, it prevents a "in the middle" match.

`[L]` means it's the last rule to process. You might consider making this `[L,NC]` so your URLs are case insensitive.

So, how would you make your change based on the your edit?

```
RewriteRule ^myappfolder/(.*)/(.*)/$ /myappfolder/?property=$1/$2/ [L]
```

You can read up on HTACCESS stuff here:

http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your reply. It helped me to understand that this is the sort of path I need to follow, but there's a couple of issues that I'm not sure it addresses. I've added an Update to my text to try to make my aims clearer, and to highlight the remaining issue. David

Comment: @David, see my update. I've also included a reference link for htaccess modifications.